# TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I'm running On Premise TFS 2018 Update2, and i'm trying to migrate to TFS online.  I'm at the point where i need to make a dacpac of my collection, and in order to do that i need to detach my collection like they outline here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=vsts#detach-coll

when i try to detach however, i get the error in the title.  Any ideas how to get past this?  The only thing i've found similar to this issue is at:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6ad3a1a-bfe0-44a9-a3e6-3442004c7687/tf400856-error-identity-management-is-not-registered-in-the-database?forum=tfsadmin

which basically says 'uinstall TFS and reinstall it back from backup', which i'd really rather not try if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the TFS was not completely configured, or something wrong during the running.

Whatever, just as mentioned in the error messages "`The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement`". It's related to the DB.

So, you can try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Restart the TFS server and the SQL server, then check it again.
- Restore the backup DB, then check it again.

It that still not work, I am afraid you have to uinstall TFS and reinstall it back from backup DB.

Comment: issue ended up being fixed by just rebooting the server.

Comment: Rebooting the TFS server fixed the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the TFS Server machine and SQL Server Machine and that resolved the issue for me.