# Error during restore of TFS backup: TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement

Tags: tfs

I am running TFS 2018 Update2, and I am trying to attach a backup which has been made without detaching it first.

Resorting to "TFSConfig offlineDetach" on these databases results in the errormessage shown below:

```
[Info   @09:30:57.248] [2018-07-12 09:30:57Z] Executing servicing step 'Copy identities to collection database'. (ServicingOperation: Snapshot; Step group: Snapshot.TfsIdentities)
[Info   @09:30:57.248] Executing step: 'Copy identities to collection database' PlatformIdentity.SnapshotIdentities (17 of 17)
[Error  @09:30:57.295] TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement.
[Info   @09:30:57.295] Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServiceNotRegisteredException: TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationResourceManagementService.DeploymentHostResourceManagementService.CreateDatabaseComponent[TComponent](IVssRequestContext deploymentRequestContext, Int32 databaseId, IVssRequestContext requestContext, String dataspaceCategory, Guid dataspaceIdentifier, DatabaseConnectionType connectionType, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationResourceManagementService.CreateComponent[TComponent](IVssRequestContext requestContext, String dataspaceCategory, Nullable`1 dataspaceIdentifier, DatabaseConnectionType connectionType, ITFLogger logger)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationResourceManagementService.CreateComponent[TComponent](IVssRequestContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDetachHandler.PreTransferSteps()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityTransferHandler`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.PlatformIdentityStepPerformer.SnapshotIdentities(IVssRequestContext requestContext, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformHostStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, IServicingStep servicingStep, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)
[Info   @09:30:57.295] [2018-07-12 09:30:57Z] Servicing step 'Copy identities to collection database' failed. (ServicingOperation: 'Snapshot'; Step group: 'Snapshot.TfsIdentities')
[Info   @09:30:57.295] 0,040819
[Info   @09:30:57.295] 0,0434132
[Info   @09:30:57.295] 5,8540154
[Error  @09:30:57.295] The error occurred while detaching the collection database 'TFS_before_projects' offline. See the log file for additional details.
[Error  @09:30:57.310] TF400711: Error occurred while executing servicing step 'Copy identities to collection database' for component Snapshot.TfsIdentities during Snapshot: TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement.
[Info   @09:30:57.310] Clearing dictionary, removing all items.
```

I've found similar issues at

[TF400856: The following service is not registered in the database: IdentityManagement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50849201/tf400856-the-following-service-is-not-registered-in-the-database-identitymanag)

and

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6ad3a1a-bfe0-44a9-a3e6-3442004c7687/tf400856-error-identity-management-is-not-registered-in-the-database?forum=tfsadmin

TFS is running perfectly with the current database. I am merely trying to restore a backup as a separate collection, both in the same SQL Server instance.

Any suggestions to actually restore this backup?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ? I face the exact same problem today on TFS 2018.2 while trying to "detachOffline" a collection DB.

Comment: Note: rebooting servers did not help.